# How could I use applescript to play keynote slids?

Tags: applescript, keynote

everyone

I try to use applescript to play my keynote slid,but occure error

```
set thisFile to "/Users/usrname/Desktop/cardtest.key"
tell application "Keynote"
    activate
    open thisFile
    start thisFile from the first slide of thisFile
end tell
```

this code will open keynote file successfully,but can't run slids.

the error was keynote error : can't make "path" become type "document".

I tried to use:

```
tell slideshow 1
```

but another error: slideshow should be the end of sentence, should not have 1.

have no idea why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are going to `start` a POSIX path rather than a Keynote document.

This is exactly what the error is telling you.

You have to use the reference to the opened document

```
set thisFile to "/Users/usrname/Desktop/cardtest.key"
tell application "Keynote"
    activate
    set currentDocument to open thisFile
    tell currentDocument to start from first slide
end tell
```

Comment: Ok,it really help, thanks a lot.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66721831/how-can-i-show-keynote-slide-randomly-by-writting-applescript